# Magento 2.3: Account Email Confirmation is not sending

Tags: magento2.3, email, smtp, mageplaza

We are using Magento cloud environment for our project. There, we want to send a confirmation email when the customer get registered on our website.

So, I have done: **Store -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Requires Email Confirmation -> Yes**

Though, I have set the option to Yes, am not receiving any email when I register.

I have installed the Mageplaza SMTP extension and getting the test email without any issues.

So, I'm not sure, what could be the issue since its a default Magento config.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you already checked the log from `/var/log/mail.log` ?

Comment: You server mail service is enable Please check and conform

Answer (score 0):

First check if email communication is disabled or not.

**Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending Settings -> Disable Email Communications**

should be **no**

After that you can check Mageplaza SMTP log if it exists and ***/var/log/mail.log***

Answer (score 0):

There can be plenty on reason why it doesn't work.

The main question is whether any other e-mails is sending correctly? Expect the test one? E.g confirmation of order? If so, then SMTP setting is correctly.

You should start with verify the Magento settings. What is important - check settings also in SCOPE VIEW, so for selected store. It can be override there.

I think the possible way it outdated e-mail template. Maybe your custom module override this e-mail template and has outdated syntax? You can override e-mail from admin panel level as well.